# Zip File containing couple .xml files and batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to be able to zip up a couple WLAN.xml files and a batch file.
Batch file will contain the commands to import those WLAN.xml's.

Can this be done directly from the zip file? Or is there a command to copy them from the zip file to a specific location (ie. c:)?

I currently have the WLAN.xml files in C:\ and my batch files specifies the location of it.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Try to explain exactly what you want to do. We can't read your mind.

Comment: What type of command are you looking for?  Do you want to run this from a batch/bash/PowerShell script?

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: To do this you would have to download the tool 72a.exe from 7zip, Although most computers nowadays already have it pre-installed

You can just use the following syntax:

7z a -tzip archive.zip -r src*.cpp src*.h

Apply your respective file path to the syntax above, and it should work.